# Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException even when app is not in background

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, android-12, startforegroundservice

I have this piece of code on MainActivity that starts a foreground service when the app is resumed.

```java
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable runnable = () -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent);
    bindService(intent, myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
};

private class AppLifecycleListener implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    @Override
    public void onResume(LifecycleOwner owner) { // app moved to foreground
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve this error without the handler.postDelayed and runnable in onResume, just by running the code inside Runnable inside **onResume**, but I've got even
more ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException crashes.

If we cannot start foreground services on background anymore (since Android API 32), what is the problem with my approach ? In other words, how to avoid this exception when it is needed to start a foreground service right after user opens the app ? (and if it's possible without WorkManager)

Dependency used:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1'
```